# Looping through members - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to loop through all members in a server using discord.py. Here's some test code that I have concocted:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("bot is online!\nname: {}\nid: {}".format(client.user.name, client.user.id))
  server = client.get_guild(ID)
  print("connected to server!\nname: {}\nid: {}".format(server.name, server.id))
  members = server.members
  print("members we've found: " + str(len(members)))
  for member in members:
    print(member.name)
```

This code works, however it's only registering about 10-20 members on all the different servers that I am testing this on.
Does anyone have a solution for this? Or a workaround?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait till the cache is done loading

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    server = client.get_guild(ID)
    print("members we've found: " + str(len(server.members)))
    for member in server.members:
        print(member.name)
```

Comment: I gave this a try. Here's my updated code:
```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.wait_until_ready()
  print("bot is online!\nname: {}\nid: {}".format(client.user.name, client.user.id))
  server = client.get_guild(ID)
  print("connected to server!\nname: {}\nid: {}".format(server.name, server.id))
  members = server.members
  print("members we've found: " + str(len(members)))
  for member in members:
    print(member.name)
```

While this increased the amount of members that was loaded, it did not solve the problem as it only registered 17 members in a 14k+ server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it captures members of the default guild. Try [iterating over all guilds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members)

Comment: This shouldn't be the case, as I am getting the guild instance from it's ID and the members that got printed were all in the guild.